# Navigate in the same dynamic tabPanel based on if condition in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I create tab panels based on a column of a dataframe. Then based on the radiobutton selected I display either a plot ot a table of either `iris` or `mtcars` datasets.

The issue is that if for example Im in `Table` mode of `mtcars` dataset and press the `Plot` mode I want to remain to the `mtcars` panel and see the `mtcars` plot instead of moving back to the `iris` panel. How could I achieve that?

```
Uni<-data.frame(NAME=c("Iris","Mtcars"))

# app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(

  title = "Tabs"
)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  dbHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("r")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      id ="tabA",
      type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Front",icon = icon("accusoft")),
      tabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table"),
               uiOutput("dyntab")

      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dyntab<-renderUI({
    do.call(tabsetPanel, 
            c(id='tabB', 
              type="tabs",
              lapply(1:nrow(Uni), function(i) {
                tabPanel(Uni[i,],icon = icon("table"),
                         if(input$radioV2=="Table"){
                           renderDataTable({
                             if(input$tabB=="Iris"){
                               datatable(iris)
                             }
                             else{
                               datatable(mtcars)
                             }
                           })

                         }
                         else{
                           renderPlot({
                             if(input$tabB=="Iris"){
                               plot(iris)
                             }
                             else{
                               plot(mtcars)
                             }
                           })
                         }
                         )
              }))
    )
  })

  output$r<-renderUI({
    if(input$tabA=="Front"){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else{
      radioButtons("radioV2", label = "Choose Mode",
                   choices = c("Table","Plot"), 
                   selected = "Table")
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You had a few things going on, one is that the creation of `dyntab` was happening every time you change a tab, which is now been fixed to render only once on start
2. We shall take advantage of the `shinyjs` with its `show` and `hide` functions to show the `radioButtons` instead of creating it all the time with `renderUI`
3. Im still not 100% on the using the above approach in the `dyntab` as you can see I had to create the `id` for the `div` in order to `show` and `hide` it, this happens because it assigns random `id`to the tables and the charts you're rendering
4. I've also took advantage of `hidden` function to hide the div upon start

---

```
Uni <- data.frame(NAME=c("Iris","Mtcars"))
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

# app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
    title = "Tabs"
)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
    dbHeader,
    dashboardSidebar(
        hidden(
            radioButtons("radioV2", label = "Choose Mode",choices = c("Table","Plot"), selected = "Table")
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        useShinyjs(),
        tags$hr(),
        tabsetPanel(
            id ="tabA",
            type = "tabs",
            tabPanel("Front",icon = icon("accusoft")),
            tabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table"), uiOutput("dyntab")

            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$tabA,{
        if(input$tabA == "Front"){
            hide("radioV2")
        }
        else{
            show("radioV2")
        }
    })

    output$dyntab <- renderUI({
        do.call(tabsetPanel,
                c(id='tabB',
                  type="tabs",
                  lapply(1:nrow(Uni), function(i) {
                      tabPanel(Uni[i,],icon = icon("table"),
                               div(id = paste0("Table",Uni$NAME[i]),DT::renderDataTable({
                                   if(Uni$NAME[i] == "Iris"){
                                       datatable(iris)  
                                   }else{
                                       datatable(mtcars)
                                   }

                               })),
                               hidden(div(id = paste0("Plot",Uni$NAME[i]),renderPlot({
                                   if(Uni$NAME[i] == "Iris"){
                                       plot(iris)  
                                   }else{
                                       plot(mtcars)
                                   }
                               })
                               ))
                      )
                  })
                )
        )
    })

    observeEvent(input$radioV2,{
        print(paste0(input$radioV2,input$tabB))
        if(input$radioV2 == 'Table'){
            show(paste0("Table",input$tabB))
            hide(paste0("Plot",input$tabB))
        }else{
            hide(paste0("Table",input$tabB))
            show(paste0("Plot",input$tabB))
        }
    })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: it works but is there a solution closer to my approach? There are others widgets created in other tabs via the uiOutput used to create radioV2. I have just posted the min. example needed but I will need to change almost all my code to adapt it.